# adding multiple objects in a single target in vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, game-development

i am a newbie in Augmented Reality, i am using Vuforia to build my AR apps. I want to add multiple objects on a single target. i would like to know how to make it possible.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should just be able to make multiple objects direct children of your `ImageTarget` within Unity. Assuming that the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` is on the `ImageTarget`, it should enable/disable any child `Renderer`s when found/lost. Have you tried this?

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing it is adding a **spawn point** as a child of the **image target**.

Then create a script say '**spawner**.cs'

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class spawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] objToBePlaced;
    public GameObject spawnPt;      //the game object (spawn point on img target)

    private GameObject someobj;
    private int rno;

    void start()
    {
       rno = Random.Range(0,3);         //Random Range for selecting gameobjects
       someobj = (GameObject)Instantiate(objToBePlaced[rno],spawnPt.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

This will enable you to spawn game objects after you add spawn point & the objects in the editor.
I am generating them randomly & also considering the spawn object are 4. However you can change it.